# Visual FoxPro OLE-DB Update Statement won't work

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to Update the Tables in my .xcs files, but nothing happens.

When I execute the Command the Method ExecuteNonQuery returns 1, which should mean that one row got updated.

My ConncetionString is: "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\vyp1rr0e.et5;Mode=ReadWrite"

```cs
try
{
    string commandText = "UPDATE ddfld SET descript = ?, comments = ? WHERE identifier = ?";
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(fConnection.ConnectionString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmdSafe = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmdSafe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descript", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = field.Description;
        cmdSafe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = field.Comments;
        cmdSafe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identifier", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = field.Id;
        cmdSafe.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why did you place your database in a temporary folder?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure you are looking at the same table that you made the update? You could verify the update, doing a select after the update.

Comment: VFP does not use "@" parameters for the names... I typically prefix the parameters like "parmDescript", "parmComments", etc... to differentiate between the actual column.  The "?" is correct as a PLACEHOLDER for VFP queries, but parameters must be in exact same order as you DO have in the code.